# SELECT query returning own username in results

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I am creating a chat application that queries an SQL table on load to display a list of the user's current friends in a datagridview. The issue I'm having is the current user also appears in the friends list.

The layout for the table is:

```
create table Friendships
(
FriendshipID int IDENTITY(100,1) Primary Key,
ReceiverID int,
SenderID int,
Approved bit,
)
```

When someone sends a request, a row is created in the table with their ID as the senderID and the person they sent it to as the ReceiverID and it is the opposite if someone sends that person a friend request, and "Approved" is set to 0 until the receiver accepts the friend request. In order to populate the datagridview, I need to query the table and return all records where the current user is either the sender or receiver, and display the person with whom they are friends. Each relationship needs to only be shown once.

One of the queries I've tried was:

```
SELECT UserID, Username, Status 
FROM Arwen_Friendships, Arwen_Users 
WHERE ReceiverID = UserID 
OR SenderID = UserID 
AND ReceiverID = @Current_User_ID 
OR SenderID = @Current_User_ID 
AND Approved =1
```

where @Current_User_ID is parameterized using the current logged in user's ID. I have tried all manner of joins, SELECT DISTINCT, and subqueries with no luck. The result of the above query returns two rows: one with the logged in user's information and one with the person who's ID is sender or receiver, and completely ignores the "Approved = 1". It will return rows with "Approved = 0".

Comment: You should check your order of operations on the where clause, its unclear what the condition actually is or what the order of operations actually is.

Comment: Definitely check your order of operations and understand the `Where and How` to use `( )` vs `(( ))` when combining AND and OR Statements you could wrap all the `AND inside a single (    )` learn some basic Sql is what I would recommend also learn to use `Table Aliasing` how is anyone supposed to know what table the ID's are from in your WHERE Clause.. ???

Comment: why is there an extra comma at the end of your table create `Approved bit,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Union all

```
(SELECT U.UserID, 
        U.Username, 
        U.Status 
   FROM Arwen_Friendships AF INNER JOIN 
        Arwen_Users U ON AF.SenderID = U.UserID 
  WHERE AF.ReceiverID = @Current_User_ID AND 
        AF.Approved = 1)

  UNION ALL 

(SELECT U.UserID, 
        U.Username, 
        U.Status 
   FROM Arwen_Friendships AF INNER JOIN 
        Arwen_Users U ON AF.ReceiverID = U.UserID 
  WHERE AF.SenderID = @Current_User_ID AND 
        AF.Approved = 1)
```

Comment: no need to union all personally speaking the OP should learn to not use `Poor Man Joins` and use Proper `INNER JOIN` to filter the results

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I've been beating my head against the wall a few days over this.

Comment: np happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful on how you structure you AND/OR's

```
SELECT UserID, Username, Status 
FROM Arwen_Friendships, Arwen_Users 
WHERE ReceiverID = UserID 
  OR  (SenderID = UserID  AND ReceiverID = @Current_User_ID )
  OR  (SenderID = @Current_User_ID  AND Approved =1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
SELECT UserID, Username, Status 
from Arwen_Friendships, Arwen_Users 
WHERE (ReceiverID = UserID OR SenderID = UserID ) 
  OR  (ReceiverID = @Current_User_ID OR SenderID = @Current_User_ID) 
  AND (Approved = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without paren all the And are processed first
You can get Approved = 0 because the Or are done last

```
SELECT UserID, Username, Status 
FROM Arwen_Friendships, Arwen_Users 
WHERE ( ReceiverID = UserID OR SenderID = UserID ) 
  AND ( ReceiverID = @Current_User_ID OR SenderID = @Current_User_ID ) 
  AND Approved =1
```